# How to compare two files in Notepad++

Tags: file, compare, notepad++

I want to compare values from two different files.
In Notepad++ version 5.0.3 we had shortcut button <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> but in version 6.6.8 I cannot find any option to compare.

Also let me know which version is most stable.

Answer (score 247):

There is the "**Compare**" plugin. You can install it via *Plugins* > *Plugin Manager*.

Alternatively you can install a specialized file compare software like [*WinMerge*](http://winmerge.org/).

Comment: WinMerge is the way to go (even while being fan of Notepad++)

Comment: @escalator Yes that is true. I installed both programs and created a NppExec script to start winmerge. If there is a split view, winmerge loads the file from the left view and compares it to the one on the right, with one click in Notepad++. The best of both worlds :)

Comment: @LarsFischer That sounds awesome. I managed to download all the plugins and WinMerge. But I don't really know how I would go about the NppExec script to start winmerge. Would you mind sharing your script? We could meet up in a [Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/). Thanks.

Comment: @Alex You would install e.g. WinMerge, then install the NppExec Plugin for Notepad++. Then create a script via Plugins -> NppExec-> Execute ... with this content: 
`npp_console keep
npp_save "$(LEFT_VIEW_FILE)" 
npp_save "$(Right_VIEW_FILE)"
npp_run "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe" "$(LEFT_VIEW_FILE)" "$(Right_VIEW_FILE)"`  
( four lines) That will run WinMerge with left and right views file (or the current file if only one view is active).  Save the script under some name and see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34611800/4086774 for assigning a shortcut to it.

Comment: @LarsFischer Thanks a lot for the script! It works like a charm.
However, I couldn't follow your instructions for assigning it to a shortcut.
Every time after I saved the script, added it as a Menu item and closed and reopened N++, my script is gone. I tried opening N++ as admin and even tried another version of NppExec. Have you ever encountered something like this? I couldn't find anything online. Also my N++ uses %appdata% so I guess it's not a portable version. What else could it be?

Comment: @Alex No I have never had issues with NppExec not storing my scripts. When you run this NppExec script: `npp_run $(PLUGINS_CONFIG_DIR)` it should open the config directory in explorer. There you find should find a file `npes_saved.txt`. It contains the scripts saved in NppExec. Does it exist? Has this file strange access rights?

Comment: @LarsFischer The whole directory `plugins` in `AppData\Roaming\Notepad++` was missing. I created it and also added the `config` folder. I even created a `npes_saved.txt` file (not sure if this was necessary). Restarted N++; and BOOM! All other files were created. Then I could follow the rest of your instructions and I'm all set - awesome!
The Folder should have been created by NppExec  but I did struggle during the installation so I guess I messed something up there.
However, thanks for bearing with me and helping me out, I really appreciate it! It really is the best of both worlds. :)

Comment: The OP asked how to do this using Notepad++, many answers diverge.

Comment: @ConradB The Compare Plugin mentioned *is a  notepad++ plugin*. This is the way to do it *using* notepad++ other than open both files and compare manually. But I have to admit that specialized tools like winmerge or kdiff3 are better.

Answer (score 82):

**Update:**

- for Notepad++ 7.5 and above use Compare v2.0.0
- for Notepad++ 7.7 and above use Compare v2.0.0 for Notepad++ 7.7, if you need to install manually follow the description below, otherwise use "**Plugin Admin**".

I use [Compare plugin 2](https://github.com/pnedev/compare-plugin/releases) for notepad++ 7.5 and newer versions. Notepad++ 7.5 and newer versions do not have **plugin manager**. You have to download and install plugins manually. And **YES** it matters if you use 64bit or 32bit (86x).

So Keep in mind, if you use a 64-bit version of Notepad++, you should also use a 64-bit version of the plugin, and the same is valid for 32-bit.

I wrote a [guideline](https://itbackyard.com/install-notepad-compare-plugin/) how to install it:

1. Start your Notepad++ in administrator mode.
2. Press <kbd>F1</kbd> to find out if your Notepad++ is 64bit or 32bit (86x), hence you need to download the correct plugin version. Download [Compare-plugin 2](https://github.com/pnedev/compare-plugin/releases).
3. Unzip Compare-plugin in a temporary folder.
4. Import the plugin from the temporary folder.
5. The plugin should appear under the Plugins menu.

> Note: 
> It is also possible to drag and drop the plugin `.dll` file
> directly in the plugin folder.
> 64bit: `%programfiles%\Notepad++\plugins`
> 32bit: `%programfiles(x86)%\Notepad++\plugins`

**Update**
Thanks to @TylerH for this update: Notepad++ Now has "**Plugin Admin**" as a replacement for the old Plugin Manager. But this method (answer) is still valid for adding plugins manually for almost any Notepad++ plugins.

> Disclaimer: the link to this guideline refer to my personal [website](https://itbackyard.com/install-notepad-compare-plugin/).

Comment: In case it was missed, step 4 import is done via the Settings menu > Import > import plugin(s).

Comment: It's far easier than this. Plugins > Plugin Admin > Tick Compare  > Install (V 7.8.4 - 32 bit)

Answer (score 24):

Update (2022-09-22): use the `ComparePlus` plug-in, and not the outdated `Compare` plug-in.

[image]

Demo:

1. [Open 2 files side-by-side](https://superuser.com/a/215918/116475)
2. `Plug-ins -> ComparePlus -> Compare`:

[image]

Features:

[image]

---

The Compare plug-in is [no longer maintained](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/23027/toggle-dark-mode-off-when-using-compare-plugin/6):

> Compare plugin will not be supported anymore (at least by me) because I consider it obsolete and because (as Peter Jones said) I am working on another plugin - ComparePlus that is Compare plugin’s successor.

For example, the Compare plug-in doesn't show the compared text clearly with dark mode:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I give the answer because I need to compare 2 files in notepad++ and there is no option available.

So first enable the plugin manager as asked by [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301700/how-to-view-plugin-manager-in-notepad/48763981#48763981), Then follow this step to compare 2 files which is free in this software.

1.open notepad++, go to

> Plugin -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager

2.Show the available plugin list, choose Compare and Install

3.Restart Notepad++.

http://www.technicaloverload.com/compare-two-files-using-notepad/

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer as it mentions that Notepad++ doesn't come with PluginManager directly and you have to first install that as @Ajay2707 mentioned in that link. This was helpful.

Comment: This is the only answer at linking a solution, how to actually *use* the plugin.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you can install "SourceForge Notepad++ Compare Plugin 1.5.6".
It provides compare functionality between two files and show the differences between two files.

Link to refer : https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-compare/files/1.5.6/

Comment: I believe that this is actually the same plugin that @LarsFischer mentioned

Comment: This is beneficial when you cannot download the plugin because of the access control matter.

Comment: Only 32-bit seems to not be rebuild recently either, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

2018 10 25. Update.

Notepad++  7.5.8 does not have plugin manager by default. You have to download plugins manually.

Keep in mind, if you use 64 bit version of Notepad++, you should also use [64 bit version](https://github.com/pnedev/compare-plugin/releases/tag/v2.0.0) of plugin. I had a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52992452/4587961).

Comment: Now it has a plugin manager again

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the latest release of Compare, here it is:

https://github.com/pnedev/compare-plugin/releases/latest

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Notepad++ with the Plugin Manager then its easy: open notepad++, go to
Plugin -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager and then search/install the Plugin „compare“. Restart Notepad++

Tutorial:
https://youtu.be/8ESbIZbXI7I

If you do not have installed the Plugin Manager:

- download the plugin manually :
  https://github.com/pnedev/compare-plugin/releases/tag/v2.0.0_npp7.7

-Copy the contents of the zip file into Notepad++'s plugins installation folder (%Notepad++_program_folder%\Plugins). use the correct archive version based on your Notepad++ architecture - x86 or x64.

- restart Notepad++