# How to compare two files?

Tags: notepad++

The version is **7.5.6**

Is there a way to make a file comparison like in `SVN` which opens on the left side the version of a file and at the right side the other version of the file ?

Comment: use textPad, by default have it

Answer (score 3):

For Notepad++ the latest plugin is [Compare v2.0.0](https://github.com/pnedev/compare-plugin/releases) (December 2016). Note that the one referenced by Rilent is v1.5.6.2 from a previous developer (June 2013).

If you aren't confined strictly to Notepad++, you may consider the open source dedicated file comparison program [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/). This program allows you to right-click two files and select WinMerge for quick comparisons.

Comment: One of the comments to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29658368/4086774 describes how you can start Winmerge with left and right view file from notepad++ using the nppexec plugin.

Answer (score 2):

With this plugin, It becomes possible : [npp-compare](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-compare/)