# Notepad++, compare plugin installation problem

Tags: notepad++

I had Notepad++ 7.5.8 (npp.7.5.8). It does not have plugin manager; previous versions used to have it. I followed these instructions.

I downloaded it from
https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-compare/

`ComparePlugin.readme.txt`

To install copy ComparePlugin.dll into the plugins directory C:\Program Files\Notepad++\Plugins

I did not work. Plugins menu did not have ComparePlugin. It had other plugins though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

2019-02-21

Alternative

Notepad++ version 7.6.2 x64 bit.

Plugins -> enter compare and install it.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Open Notepad as Administrator
Settings > Import > Import plugin(s)

[image]

Then select the ComparePlugin.dll, now notepad should prompt you a message to restart your notepad in order to make the change take effect

Re-open your notepad now, the compare plugin should be appear at Plugin now :)

Comment: This worked for me. It seems like the normal method of installing plugins was not working on my work PC.

Answer (score 2):

2020-05-27

Update: Alternative

Notepad++ version 7.8.6 x64 bit.

`click Plugins on Menu bar`
 -> `click Plugins Admin...`
  -> `type Compare in search bar`
   -> `check Compare checkbox`
    -> `click Install button`
     -> `click Yes on dialog box`.

Answer (score 1):

2018-10-25

If you use 64 bit Notepad++, use 64 bit version of the [plugin](https://github.com/pnedev/compare-plugin/releases/tag/v2.0.0).

After I have struggled for some time, I found a solution.

1) I updated Notepad++ from `7.5.8` into `7.5.9`. After I applied * ComparePlugin.dll* which I have downloaded from the [link in the question](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-compare/), it showed me an error that I used 64 bit version of Notepad++ and 32 bit version of the plugin.

2) I got the plugin of 64 bit version from [git hub page](https://github.com/pnedev/compare-plugin/releases/tag/v2.0.0). I put the `ComparePlugin.dll` into the plugins directory.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin directory differs in different NPP versions, and installations. Be sure that you placed your plugins into the right folder.

There is a feature from NPP-v7.6.4 to get this folder:

**`Plugins -> Open Plugins Folder...`**

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but in case anyone stumbles across this still needing an answer I have a weird fix.

For some reason my installation is limiting the number of plugins I can have to a max of 3. So when I uninstalled 'Mime Tools' and then tried to install the plugin I wanted (Compare) it worked.

Not sure why Notepad++ is doing this but it temporarily solves the issue if you have a specific plugin you need to use.

Answer (score 1):

Update (2022-09-22): use the `ComparePlus` plug-in, and not the obsolete `Compare` plug-in. It has many more features and work much better in dark mode.

To install it:

[image]

Demo:

1. [Open 2 files side-by-side](https://superuser.com/a/215918/116475)
2. `Plug-ins -> ComparePlus -> Compare`:

[image]

Features:

[image]

---

The Compare plug-in is [no longer maintained](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/23027/toggle-dark-mode-off-when-using-compare-plugin/6):

> Compare plugin will not be supported anymore (at least by me) because I consider it obsolete and because (as Peter Jones said) I am working on another plugin - ComparePlus that is Compare plugin’s successor.

For example, the Compare plug-in doesn't show the compared text clearly with dark mode:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are on your work machine and the domain is blocked by your network administrator, an easy fix is to disconnect from your company intranet, connect to the internet via wifi or using your mobile phone usb tethering. Then try to install the plugin, it will work.

Comment: This answers does not relate to the question. Here you provide a work-around for blocked domain.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly why I couldn't download the plugin! Up-vote from me.

Answer (score 0):

2022. 07.27
      Both of following versions seemed not compatible each other:
      npp.8.4.2.Installer.x64.exe (https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v8.4.2/) and
      ComparePlugin.v1.5.6.2.bin.zip (https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-compare/postdownload).

NPP was installed in a 64bit machine within an isolated netwwork.
Then the instruction as given in the readme was followed.
But it failed to detect Compare Plugin.

ComparePlugin_v2.0.0_X64.zip will be checked today.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to check the version between "Notepad++" and "ComparePlugin".

Please note: (see [Unable to install Compare Plugin](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/18520/unable-to-install-compare-plugin/7) - scroll down for "PeterJones")

- For Notepad++ v8.2.2 an newer, you should installing ComparePlugin v2.0.0.
- For Notepad++ v7.7 thru Notepad++ v8.2.1, you nedd to use ComparePlugin v2.0.1.
- If you have older than Notepad++ v7.7, I highly recommend updating Notepad++ first, but you can use ComparePlugin v2.0.0 for such ancient Notepadd++ version.

Download link: [ComparePlugin](https://github.com/pnedev/comparePlus)

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:
**By installing from Notepad**
Go to Plugins->Plugin Admin
Select the Compare checkbox and click install after notepad++ get restarted compare plugin is added you can use this.

Method 2:
**By download plugin and add it Manually**
step 1:First download the Plugins for Compare from this git location https://github.com/pnedev/compare-plugin/releases/tag/v2.0.2
step 2:Extract the zip move ComparePlugin.dll into the folder ComparePlugin and copy the folder  ComparePlugin.
step 3:Go to Settings->Import->Import Plugin(s)
It will open the folder location of notepad++ and open the folder plugins paste the folder ComparePlugin which was copied at step3.
close the notepad++ and reopen it.Now you can work with compare plugin.

**Note/Edit**: In case Notepad++ is installed on C:/Program Files and installation is restricted by admin, please move Notepad++ to user folder you have access to (i.e.C:/Users/your_username/Notepad++) and apply Method 2.